# Delete files that exist in the source with rsync

Tags: rsync, rm

I have a folder on server "A" called `./delete`.

I want to delete everything in the folder `./stuff` on server "B" that exists in the `./delete` folder on server "A".

Its like the reverse of rsync. instead of transferring files from `a:/delete` to `b:/stuff` I want to just delete all the files that are in both places on server "B".

like a `--delete-on-destination` flag or something.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't think that rsync can resolve your problem. But another sync tool might be able to help you. Take a look at [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Unison has many features and can sync two folders on different machines. Unison is written in OCaml that is a charming functionional language.

Rsync is a unidirectional sync tool.Unison is a bidirectional sync tool.

Comment: thanks. i used a series of scripts to accomplish what I wanted, but this might work.

Comment: How would Unison help here? The purpose isn't to synchronize the two directories at all.

Comment: after looking at unison, I figure it was just a blanket answer without really reading the problem I am faced with.

Comment: Unison can keep the two folder on different machine sync.If clientA delete some files,clientB will delete some files too!

Comment: @chovy It looks like this doesn't actually answer your question; would you consider unaccepting the answer to avoid giving other readers the impression that it does?

Answer (score 0):

File copy tools such as rsync aren't going to help you easily since you don't want to copy any files.

The straightforward approach of listing the files on server A and erasing these files on server B is a good one in most circumstances. It's easier to cope with arbitrary file names if your servers' `find` and `xargs` commands understand null separators (Linux, *BSD, Cygwin). From A:

```
cd ./delete
find . ! -type d -print0  | ssh B 'cd /path/to/stuff && xargs -0 rm -f'
```

This may leave some empty directories behind. You can delete all empty directories (even the ones that were empty before) with

```
ssh B 'cd /path/to/stuff && find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null'
```

If you only want to remove directories that existed on the source side, you'll need to use the list again:

```
find . -depth -type d -print0  | ssh B 'cd /path/to/stuff && xargs -0 rmdir'
```

If there are directory trees on A that contain a lot of files and don't exist on B, this transfers the whole list of files to erase where a well-chosen `rm -rf` on B would do the same work locally on B but would save a lot of bandwidth in the transfer. This is the kind of situation where a file synchronization tool would fare well. You could run `rsync -nv` and try to parse the output, but it isn't easy to build something reliable on this.

Comment: this only works on files. not directories, and I believe it deletes the files from A, not B.

Comment: @chovy Indeed, I'd misread your question. I don't think file synchronization tools will help much since you aren't copying files. Although, hmmm, there might be a way to build something with `rsync --remove-source-files --compare-dest`

Comment: i don't understand what `--compare-dest` does.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this also, and decided to just write a ruby script for it.

Here you go:

https://github.com/saizai/utils/blob/master/rm_dupes_from.rb